# Session cookie is missing in Android web browser and some of nokia web browsers

Tags: android, spring-mvc, session-cookies, sessionid, nokiabrowser

I have developed a Java EE web application using Spring 2.5. This application has authentication step and if user enter correct log-in data he will redirect to a secure page. My Issue is in Android web browser and some of nokia web browsers does not send session cookie. However this application works fine in all other web browsers and mobile web browsers. I have tested following ways, By Adding session Attribute after logged in then check attribute each request By Adding session scope bean

in both ways i was unable to resolve the issue. My environment is Apache Tomcat 5.5 , Java 1.5

Thanks and waiting for a help from all of you.

Steps to create:

1. There is a log-in screen
2. User enter user data and click submit button
3. In the server side it capture the request and if user data is correct user will be redirect to the secure site ( up to now it's working as it should be in every browser )
4. user click a link on the secure site which will go in a valid session check interceptor ( in this step,I have noticed I'm not getting authorized session in Nokia 6300 web browser and in Sony Ericsson Xperia built in web browser).

However in all other web PC web browsers and in mobile web browsers such as Nokia E 71 built in web browser, opera mini sending back JSessionId. Please note that using above mention Nokia 6300 and Xperia can logged in to Yahoo mail and G mail.

Answer (score 1):

Check the expires time on the cookie (in the Set-Cookie response header) and check the time/date settings on the phone. Make sure the phone and the server are both set to the correct time.